# Why could get a value by ctx.Value in a canceled or timeout context?

Tags: go

`ctx2` add some information on `ctx1`, and use it as the “parent context” to create `ctx3`, but why still get the value by `ctx2.Value` `ctx3.Value` when the parent context is already timeout or canceled ?

https://go.dev/play/p/UXiXzlTDWuQ

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    ctx1, cancelFunc1 := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 1*time.Second)
    defer cancelFunc1()

    ctx2 := context.WithValue(ctx1, "tenant-id", "my_tenant")

    ctx3, cancelFunc2 := context.WithTimeout(ctx2, 3*time.Second)
    defer cancelFunc2()

    log.Println(1, ctx2.Value("tenant-id").(string))
    log.Println(2, ctx3.Value("tenant-id").(string))
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    log.Println(3, ctx2.Value("tenant-id").(string))
    log.Println(4, ctx3.Value("tenant-id").(string))
    //withTimeout.Done() or
    cancelFunc1()
    // still does not work
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    //could still get value in closed context here no matter canceled or timeout
    log.Println(5, ctx2.Value("tenant-id").(string))
    log.Println(6, ctx3.Value("tenant-id").(string))
}
```

Comment: A canceled or timedout context doesn't "vanish" and still contains it's value, the context is just done.

Comment: To put it the other way: Why would you expect that a canceled/timed-out context looses it's values?

Comment: Imagine your base context store a logger. You wrap the context with a cancellable context. You cancel. You still can retrieve the logger.